# How can I use LOWER on SELECT of JSON column using Sequelize and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm not sure if I need to go to raw for this, query but I hope not.

I have code like:

```
let where = {
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

I then loop through keys that may be sent from a query param, that would need to search within a JSON datatype.

```
const string_json_keys = ['title', 'description'];
let jsonHits = [];
string_json_keys.forEach(key => {
  if (params[key]) {
    let functionalWhere = sequelizeInstance.where(sequelizeInstance.fn('lower', sequelizeInstance.col(`metadata->$.${key}`)), params[key].toLowerCase());
    jsonHits.push(functionalWhere);

  }
});

if (jsonHits.length) {
  where[Op.and] = jsonHits;
}
```

Given a title of `Hello World` I want to normalize search to all lower case since JSON is case sensitive in MySQL. Meaning I want to say `WHERE LOWER(title) = hello world`.

The above code converted to

```
WHERE (lower(`metadata->$`.`title`) =
```

I am not sure how to change that to one string of `metadata->$.title` as needed. I tried escaping the `.` with `\.` but had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`->` is shorthand for `JSON_EXTRACT`. I need to use that method, followed by LOWER to get what I want. Using `JSON_UNQUOTE` is so I can compare my user-input string to an actual string, rather than a JSON object of `"hello world"`. The user wouldn't be searching with quotes so it wouldn't return anything.

```
let extractCall = sequelizeInstance.fn('JSON_EXTRACT', sequelizeInstance.col('metadata'), `$.${key}`);
let unquoteCall = sequelizeInstance.fn('JSON_UNQUOTE', extractCall);
let functionalWhere = sequelizeInstance.where(sequelizeInstance.fn('LOWER', unquoteCall), params[key].toLowerCase());
```

I also raised an issue to allow the shorthand https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9332. This would make the code a bit cleaner.

I should also note `JSON_UNQUOTE` isn't technically needed to fulfill my question of my ability to properly use `LOWER`, but I imagine it's a common need for people wanting to search string values vs actual JSON objects.